# How do I get openGL to render a coloured quad?

Tags: java, opengl

Basically, I am trying to let openGL draw a bunch of quads. Each of these quads has different colours. Now my problem is that when I call glColor4f(), the colour is not applied on the material. I found out that that was because I had been using textures somewhere else in the rendering process, so I disabled that. Still, not result. After some googling I came across glColorMaterial(), which did display the quads correctly, but because I used glColour4f() to colour each of the quads, each of the 3D textures objects on the stage were tinted. So now I am a bit stuck; I want to have lighting enabled on my 3D objects, yet those few quads should just be drawn in a flat colour, without any lighting whatsoever. What is the openGL method of doing this?
My openGL context setup:

```
glViewport(0, 0, dim.width, dim.height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(60.0f, (float)(dim.width/dim.height), 0.1f, 10000.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glClearColor(94.0f/255.0f, 161.0f/255.0f, 255.0f/255.0f, 0.5f);
glClearDepth(1.0);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); 
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1); 
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Comment: I don't know the exact answer for this... but OpenGL is very state-based and the state is always taken into account whenever you render a vertex. So... I can't remember how to actually *do* it, but you basically want to disable whatever you enabled to get textures, materials, and lighting to be considered, then render your quads, then re-enable everything again. (**EDIT:** Use `glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)`. That should hopefully do it.)

Comment: @fazo: The OP had some textures on other quads that should be rendered with lighting.

Comment: glColorMaterial with GL_EMISSION should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Platinum Azure said, you need to disable lighting and texturing right before drawing your quads, and then turn it back on afterwards. Like this:

```
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

// Draw quads

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

You should be fine to just use `glColorf` as usual (you don't need `glColorMaterial`).

Comment: it only resets the lighting again, but I think I can figure that one out. thank you all for your help :)